# Unexpected Indent error coffeescript

Tags: javascript, class, compiler-errors, coffeescript, indentation

I get an unexpected indent error when I try compiling this code:

```
class permanentItem extend Item 
    add: ->
        super()

    remove: ->
        super()
```

It is on the second line `add: ->`. I have tried commenting that and it still gives me the same error on `remove: ->`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. It should be `extends` instead of `extend`:

```
class permanentItem extends Item 
    add: ->
        super()

    remove: ->
        super()
```